# Where is the Ring Buffer in linux kernel networking?

Tags: networking, data-structures, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I know when you recv data from NIC, there is a ring buffer that NIC DMA data into it, and some NIC supports multiple ring buffer. But I wonder where does the ring buffer store, in which struct, or should I manually alloc a ring buffer when writing a Network Driver?

where does the ring buffer store, and what does it look like, better if show me the source code, thank you a lot.

Comment: It depends on the the hardware. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: "*I know ... there is a ring buffer ...*" --  Assuming by "*network*" you mean Ethernet, the typical Ethernet (aka EMAC) device does not have a "*ring buffer*". Rather there's a ring *list*, and each entry in that list is a pointer to a buffer for an Ethernet frame. So it could be called a ring of buffer*s*; each buffer will contain only one frame (or a partial frame).

Comment: Actrually I'm working on a FPGA with Xilinx XDMA IP Core and trying to learn to write a Network Driver for it. I read the LDD and some other book, but I have only learnt the basic framework, there are lots of details I don't kown. Is there any simple network driver with source code that I can imitate? Thanks for some recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

[image it](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-shared-ring-buffers-FIFO-between-NIC-and-the-device-driver_fig1_341642118):
[image]

your question ---- where does the ring buffer store, in which struct, or should I manually alloc a ring buffer when writing a Network Driver?

- it's created by net driver, the ring buffer, using kernel's fifo data structor, and its memory is allocated through kernel's method, thus located in kernel's data segment.
- the kernel(without net driver) called net driver to pull up the nic(hardware), and the net driver manage the ring buffer for the kernel's ip protocal stack to use.
- when data come from nic, nic do 2 things(which is not drawn in the picture above):

  1. save data through DMA into the ring buffer
  2. hardware interrupt: tell cpu(the kernel thread) to recv data from the ring buffer